# Query only those documents where image field is not empty

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping `**(dynamic strict on the type)**`

```
               "created": {
                  "type": "date"
               },
               "images": {
                  "properties": {
                     "checksum": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": false
                     },
                     "path": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": false
                     },
                     "url": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "index": false
                     }
                  }
               },
```

I want to query documents where there is a image present

I tried couple of combinations but no luck so far.

This is the last i tried

```
POST catalog/_search
{
   "query": {
      "script": {
         "script": "doc['images'].values.length > 0"
      }
   }
}

POST catalog/_search
{
   "query": {
      "script": {
         "script": "doc['images.url'].values.length > 0"
      }
   }
}
```

But here it says that field data is not true for text fields. Is there anyway I can do this without changing my mapping.

Ideally this should give me all the records where there is no images. But this is returning all records

```
POST catalog/_search
{
   "query": {
       "bool": {
           "must_not": [
              {
                  "exists": {
                      "field": "images"
                  }
              }
           ]
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the example document in which there is a image.

```
 {
            "_index": "catalog-2018-03-03",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "151755703145e27e4983a0bd1b70be44",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "merchant": {
                  "link": "http://shophive.com/",
                  "name": "shophive"
               },
               "images": [],
               "updated": "2018-03-18T13:06:33.583480",
               "name": "Plantronics Savi Talk",
               "created": "2018-03-18T13:06:33.583459",
               "url": "http://www.shophive.com/plantronics-savi-talk",
               "price": {
                  "new": 24999,
                  "old": 24999,
                  "discount_percent": 0
               },
               "category": {
                  "level_1": {
                     "url": "computers/tablets/networking",
                     "name": "Computers/Tablets & Networking "
                  },
                  "level_2": {
                     "url": "tablets/ebook-readers",
                     "name": "Tablets & eBook Readers"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
```

**Updated**

With the below query I am expecting that elasticsearch would return the documents in which image is missing

```
POST catalog/product/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must_not": [
            {
               "exists": {
                  "field": "images"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

But the result i receive is all the documents in my index and apparently every document has one image. Here is the example document i get with above query

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 20967,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "catalog-2018-03-03",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "151755703145e27e4983a0bd1b70be44",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "merchant": {
                  "link": "http://shophive.com/",
                  "name": "shophive"
               },
               "images": [
                  {
                     "url": "http://www.shophive.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/165x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/l/plantronics_savi_talk.jpg",
                     "path": "full/8e3587bd2b6107f0beafa9b1ba05f476539be0a8.jpg",
                     "checksum": "fa74ade23c8e80e9590d48d4e59b6b64"
                  }
               ],
               "updated": "2018-03-18T13:06:33.583480",
               "name": "Plantronics Savi Talk",
               "created": "2018-03-18T13:06:33.583459",
               "url": "http://www.shophive.com/plantronics-savi-talk",
               "price": {
                  "new": 24999,
                  "old": 24999,
                  "discount_percent": 0
               },
               "category": {
                  "level_1": {
                     "url": "computers/tablets/networking",
                     "name": "Computers/Tablets & Networking "
                  },
                  "level_2": {
                     "url": "tablets/ebook-readers",
                     "name": "Tablets & eBook Readers"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Post an example of a document with out image

Comment: @sramalingam24 I updated my question with the example document Thanks

Comment: @RaheelKhan In the example document attached, I see empty images array though you mentioned as an example in which an image is present

Comment: @RaheelKhan Can you attach one document once you executed must_not exists query

Comment: @Chan15 Please check the updated part in my question I have attached the query and example document. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should leave out the the square brackets in the query as you only have one clause

```
POST /catalog/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "images"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns the docs with out images for me and if you need only those that have images

```
POST /catalog/_search
    {
        "query": {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "images"
                    }
                }

    }
```

Comment: Even without square brackets it doesn't work not sure what is the problem. Normal exists query gives zero results. But there are only few documents in which images are missing. So atleast it should return me rest of the documents where images are present

Comment: I am assuming you are doing the POST on /catalog-2018-03-03/_search and not /catalog/_search which was just for example

Comment: Can you please post the output of GET /_cat/aliases?v